# NodeJS Mysql module throws ETIMEDOUT error on remote DB

Tags: mysql, node.js

Good day!

I'm trying to connect to a MySQL database using Node JS. I npm i'd mysql and included it on top of my file. When I run my code I get nothing. I did console logged the connection at the end of the script which gave me a valid connection model in return. I just never seem to reach the funciton within .connect nor the query or ping.

When I connect to localhost (running a Wamp server) the connection succeeds and I retrieve some console logs. I've tried connecting to a second external DB, giving me the same error.

The error I receive:

ETIMEDOUT. At Connection_handleConnectTimeout. And an error in protocol.js while handshaking Fatal true. (I omitted some text).

I have the latest mysql module installed.

```
   var mysql = require('mysql');
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: 'MY_HOST_IP',
        database: 'MY_HOST_DB',
        user: 'MY_HOST_USR',
        password: 'MY_PW'
    });
    connection.connect(function (err) {
        console.log('conecting');
        if (err) {
            console.error('Error connecting: ' + err.stack);
        }

        console.log('Connected as id ' + connection.threadId);
    });
    connection.query('SELECT * from accounts', function (error, results, fields) {
        if (error) console.log(error);
        console.log('account ', results[0]);
    });
    connection.ping(function (error) { console.log('pingerror'); });
```

## Edit:

The above code times out while connecting to either one of two externally hosted Databases (using their IP address). The hosts of these DB's say nothing is wrong with the settings.
I try to connect from a 127.0.0.1:22005 connection towards the database, maybe there lies a problem?
When I put above code in a stand alone JS file and run it with node  in my commandline it connects.

Comment: in place of localhost try with ip.

Comment: Like 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost?

Comment: yeah or network ip of the machine as wthell. Try both

Comment: Thats weird. If I put 127.0.0.1 as host it also times out... Is there some flag I need to set? Edit: If i put 127.0.0.1 as localAddress it works. When I put my external DB host (IP) as localAddress I obviously get user not allowed access on localhost. What should I instead put as host then.

Comment: On mobile now will post a solution  tomorrow.

Comment: can you check your .hosts file entries please?

Comment: Where can I find this? I am not the one hosting the DB.

Comment: Then do what works for you. Simple.

Answer (score 0):

You need give grant all privileges to all / specific I.P as below :

// Below query creates user with no password, for setting different passwords check this : http://knowmysql.blogspot.com/2013/09/mysql-grant-password-error-error-1372.html

**CREATE USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED VIA mysql_native_password USING '';**

// add privileges

**GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%';**

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The user I'm using has exactly 'USR'@'%'.

Answer (score 0):

By default the Node MySQL module will connect to port 3306. If you want to connect to a custom port (e.g 22005), you need to specify it by adding `port: 22005` to your object that you are passing to mysql.createConnection(). You should also make sure that that port on   MY_HOST_IP is reachable from the host where you are running your Node instance on the network level.

Comment: Thanks for replying.The mysql server listens to port 3306. It's only the server I'm using to connect to the mysql DB that uses 22005 (just for itself). This worked fine before. I can even connect from terminal, just not using this server. So the host is reachable.

Comment: Is Node running on Linux, and if yes, do you have root on that host? If yes, `sudo strace -p $(pidof node | tr ' ' ',') -f -e network` and then do something to make the server try to connect. This will show which host it is trying to connect to and on which port.